# Restarting Python Script

Tags: python

I would like to know if any python script is terminated in the middle due to powerloss or some other stuff,Can the python script be restarted where it left?.
Is it possible anyhow that the script restarts from only where the code has not been executed.

THANKS.

Comment: Not by default, you need to save states on variables and re-initiate them yourself. Unless you run it in a container or something that has states.

Comment: No. There is no [reasonable] way to do what you're describing.

Comment: Suggestion: if you think you need this, then you (or an experienced software engineer who can help you) should consider redesigning your application in a more stateless way, if possible.

Comment: @ronrothmanℝℝ  Bro can you tell any other language in which this can be possible .